# nginx php-fpm index.php doesn't load

Tags: debian, php, nginx

I have a quite simple setup with nginx and php-fpm, howsoever when I try to access my website with `my-website.com` I get a 403 forbidden error, If I access `my-website.com/index.php` everything works fine.
This is what's showing up in my log:

```
a.ipv4.addr.here - user  [14/Dec/2013:11:46:41 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403  192 "https://my-website.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36"
```

This is the output of `ls -l` of the htdocs directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 14 www-data www-data 4.0K Dec 12 16:02 htdocs
```

I am performing a http-redirect to https to force ssl, here's the config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/my-domain.com/htdocs/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm /index.php;

        server_name my-domain.com;
        rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;

}
```

And here is the Server config listening on Port 443:

```
server {
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:443;
        server_name my-domain.com;

        root /var/www/my-domain.com/htdocs/;
        index   index.php index.html /index.php;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/my-domain.log;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/my-domain.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/my-domain.com.key;

        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                auth_basic              "Restricted:";
                auth_basic_user_file    .htpasswd;
        }


        location ~ \.php$ {

                 auth_basic              "Restricted:";
                 auth_basic_user_file    .htpasswd;
                 fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                 fastcgi_index index.php;
                 include fastcgi_params;
        }
        #deny access on dotfiles
        location ~ /\. {
                 deny  all;
        }

}
```

And here is the `ls -l` output for the index.php:

```
-rwxr-x--x 1 www-data www-data 2.4K Dec 12 11:11 index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `index index.php` to your `location /` block, or nginx won't know that you're trying to display index.php by default.

The `fastcgi_index` option is of no help since it is only considered if the URI ends in .php...

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't work. 
I now have:
location / {
    index index.php;
    [...]
}

Comment: Have you made sure that all directories to your http root are accessible for the webserver, too? (/var, /var/www, ...)

Comment: It was infact a permission issue, thank you for your help!